# Determinar o índice de um carácter numérico

Tags: powershell

Como posso armazenar a posição do primeiro carácter numérico de uma `string`?

Exemplo:

```
$NomeEstacao = "Atendimento05" # posição 11 (carácter 0)
$NomeEstacao = "Direcao46" # posição 7 (carácter 4)
```

Tentei usar `$a.IndexOf("\d").` para encontrar a posição mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$NomeEstacao = "Atendimento05" 
if ($NomeEstacao  -match "(?<digito>\d)") {
    $pos = $NomeEstacao.IndexOf($Matches.digito)
    Write-Host $pos
}
```

O `-match` procura o primeiro digito na `string` e depois o `.IndexOf(...)` retorna a posição do digito. Tem ainda o bónus de se quiser saber qual foi o primeiro digito encontrado.

Comment: Sei que o site não recomenda comentários de agradecimento. Mas, obrigado pela dica. Será muito útil.

Comment: Nao ha problema, normalmente o esperado e recomendado e que vote na resposta se o ajudou e, como no seu caso, se a pergunta for sua, marque a resposta como soluçao. Dito isto nao ha problema em agradecer.